# How can I access to the index of list inside of a dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Is there any other way to call out the index of a list inside of a dictionary.
For instance:

```
Dummy_dictionary = {"Yahoo": ["yaya", "my"], "my": ["lol", "yalo"]}
print(range(len(Dummy_dictionary["Yahoo"])))
```

The output would be:
range(0, 2)    as in the list it should be (0, 1)
I appreciate for any help.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to ask.

Comment: What means "range of a list"?

Comment: Index of value alone as the value is a list and I want to get the index of that value not including index of the key together.

Comment: An index means usually the position (as int) of a value contained in a sequential type like a list or tuple.

Answer (score 0):

You can call the index by:

```
Dummy_dictionary["Yahoo"][index]
```

This is basically doing the following:
`Dummy_dictionary["Yahoo"]` returns the list `["yaya", "my"]` and essentially youre just indexing that list by doing the above.

This answers what the title of your question suggests, what you mean to ask in the actual question is unclear

Comment: That is what I want. Pardon me for being unclear, I am still a rookie.

Comment: Glad i could help and keep going!!! You can make sure people unserstand the question by adding what you would like to do and what is the expected result. And make sure you accept this answer if it answers your question, [read more](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers#:~:text=Choose%20one%20answer%20that%20you,the%20answer%2C%20at%20any%20time.)